# Bash environment breaks after calling matlab from command line

Tags: linux, bash, matlab

I have a strange problem: when calling matlab command from the shell , as follows:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "SomeFunction(SomeParameter);quit;"
```

it works fine, but on exiting matlab breaks down something in bash environment - I can type commands but see no display of what I am typing, but see results of command execution. It seems it is redirected somewhere, but I can't figure out how to get it back and why it was redirected. Hitting return repeats printing of the prompt and I get smth like:

```
anton@richter:~/data$ anton@richter:~/data$ anton@richter:~/data$ anton@richter:~/data$
```

Any hint/help on this would be useful.

Details: I am using Ubuntu server. 
Anton

Answer (score 3):

`echo` has been turned off.

Doing `reset` is the quickest solution, as it's probably messed up more than just echo.
  But to just reset echo, you can do `stty echo`.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, that works. How do I turn it back on in the script? just "reset" each time? Seems excessive .

Comment: typing "stty echo"  does the minimal job! thanks for the lead!

Comment: Yes, and it's actually the terminal line settings which have been altered here - it has nothing to do with bash.

Comment: might be good to do stty sane as that will reset a lot of options to predictable state.