# When Matlab crashes, X11 connection breaks on Mac OS

Tags: matlab, x11-forwarding

I'm using MATLAB (2013a) on a linux machine remotely.
I'm forwarding X11 via ssh using `ssh -X` (OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013).
The X11 server is XQuartz 2.7.4 (xorg-server 1.13.0) on a Mac OS 10.8.5.

When my MATLAB crashes, it somehow kills the X11 connection, and I need to reconnect via ssh to re-estabilish a fresh X11, otherwise MATLAB refuses to start.
Is it normal for an X11 application to do things like this? Is there a way to fix the X11 without reconnecting via ssh?

This happens when I don't have splash (-nosplash), no gui, no editor, no plots as well.

EDIT: I am running MATLAB over a shell (`bash`) inside `tmux` (or sometimes `screen`).

Comment: Are you launching MATLAB via the `ssh` command or manually after you get a shell?

Comment: @chappjc I run it via `screen` or `tmux`. updated the question.

Comment: `tmux` is nice!  Anyway, I had a couple questions in my initial answer.  Can you have a look?

Comment: @chappjc I will. When it crashes next time which should be soonish.

Comment: Nice question, I always had this issue and never though of making a question trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Werner are you also using Mac OS? I wonder if this happens in linux as well...

Comment: @Memming I use Mac OS. But the issue that would happened for me (and other people from my laboratory) is that when we connect remotely to a screen on the laboratory server and run matlab, if matlab would crash, it would make the screen quite crazy (you wouldn't be able to see what you are typing and when you press enter it would show the bash `PS1` line again). The only way would finish the screen and reopen it. Have you tried ssh -Y as chappjc recommends?

Comment: @Werner when your terminal is messed up, you can always try `reset` and/or `stty sane`. :)

Comment: I see, didn't know about that. I'll try if this happens to me again x)

Comment: For testing purposes it may be convenient to have a way to crash Matlab. @Amro has found something for that in response to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342688/difference-between-empty-matlab-struct-s-and-all-elements-s

Comment: So you log in to the linux box using ssh -X, then you start tmux/screen, then you start matlab – correct? Did you try whether the problem also happens without tmux/screen? If not, you could simply use several ssh logins in several MacOS terminal windows instead.

Comment: @Memming - Please give the -Y syntax a shot, since it is given a as a potential solution by the MathWorks for exactly this problem: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1NDEZ0/?product=SL&solution=1-1NDEZ0

Comment: Wow, you really can crash MATLAB with just `S = struct(); S = setfield(S, {}, 'g', {}, 0)`!  Nice tip for crazy people like us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the `DISPLAY` variable set properly for X11 forwarding to work correctly -- something `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` should do for you.  What is the value of `DISPLAY` before and after the crash (`echo $DISPLAY`)?  It should be something like `localhost:10.0`.  I'm wondering if the variable gets messed up does not exit cleanly.

Also, [try using `-Y` instead of `-X`](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1NDEZ0/?product=SL&solution=1-1NDEZ0) to see if that makes any difference.  If that  doesn't help, try adding `ForwardX11Trusted yes` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: `DISPLAY` is still `localhost:10.0`.

Comment: Oh well.  That is what used to go wrong when I used MATLAB on a Linux with Cygwin's X Window's server.

Comment: Yes. Actually the `-Y` switch makes it much more stable. Let me test a bit more and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to show the complete sequence of commands you use to initiate the connection and start MATLAB, along with any error messages. For example:

```
# batch mode
client$ ssh -v -x user@server           # small "x" disables X11 forwarding
server$ unset DISPLAY
server$ nohup matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -noFigureWindows -nosplash \
          -r "ver; quit;" > m_output.out 2>&1 < /dev/null &

# interactive mode
client$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
client$ ssh -v -X user@server           # enable X11 forwarding
server$ matlab
```

A few ideas:

- turn on more verbose output (`ssh -vv`), and investigate the reason the SSH connection was closed (debug output messages or any log files)
- are you directly running a command from `ssh`, or is this done in two steps (connect using `ssh`, then interactively start command from allocated shell)?
- If I understood correctly, this also happens when not using X11 forwarding?
- does this happen when using [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) or screen/tmux as well? See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)
- try adding `TCPKeepAlive` to your ssh config
- how about using auto-reconnect SSH connections
- are you using any custom SSH configurations? (if so show the relevant parts from `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` files)
- try running another process in the background before starting MATLAB

It's been [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021166/97160) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10301929/97160) that MATLAB can sometimes [mess up the bash shell](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-fix-the-display.html) when it returns. MathWorks recommended using a different shell instead (like tcsh or zsh).